# Is a polytropic process $PV^{n} = const$ with $n<0$ actually possible?

Tags: thermodynamics

I can't see any reason it shouldn't.
However, Wikipedia says:

> Negative exponents reflect a process where work and heat flow simultaneously in or out of the system. In the absence of forces except pressure, such a spontaneous process is not allowed by the second law of thermodynamics.

First and foremost, is that part

> Negative exponents reflect a process where work and heat flow simultaneously in or out of the system.

actually true, and how can one prove it?

Then, how this violates the II law?
I would think it is possible to do work and give heat away as long as this is done at the expense of internal energy.
Maybe the violation could be there in the case of an open, steady-flow (thus $\frac{\Delta E_{system}}{dt} =0$ ) system?

Comment: The key word in the Wiki statement is "spontaneous."  A polytropic process is reversible (non-spontaneous).

Comment: @ChetMiller Oh, so Wikipedia is plain wrong, since i found that statement under the _polytropic index n<0_ part (in fact, the whole page is about polytropic processes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytropic_process ).

Comment: @ChetMiller Is the first part of the statement (heat and work flow both in/out) also incorrect? I'm thinking about a piston receiving heat and expanding against a spring. Here the pressure and volume would both raise (take for example $n=-1$, so $\frac{P}{V}=const$ ) and the system would perform work. Hence the Wiki statement would be false.

Comment: I don’t understand what they are saying in their comment about negative values of the exponent.

Comment: The flow of heat and work during the process is generally correct for a polytropic process.